# dsniff not showing

Tags: debian, terminal

How can I check a package?

I installed `dsniff` and I can't access any of it's tools from terminal. I type `arpspoof` and nothing. <kbd>Tab</kbd> key doesn't autocomplete.

Dsniff is installed using `sudo apt-get install dsniff`.

Running debian jessie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arpspoof` should normally be installed in `/usr/sbin`. You should check that your package did that as well, and if the file is executable:

```
dpkg -L dsniff | fgrep arpspoof
ls -l /usr/bin/arpspoof
```

Then check that `/usr/sbin` is in your PATH:

```
if [[ ":$PATH:" == *":/usr/sbin:"* ]]; then printf "path ok\n"; fi
```

Most likely `/usr/sbin` is not in the PATH of your non-root user.